# How to set up routes correctly for webapi controller so id is picked up as part of url instead of querystring

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm having an issue with getting urls to resolve to my controllers properly by getting the id from the url rather than a querystring parameter.  I have a .net webapi project set up with the following folder structure.

```
Root
  Controllers
    v1
      Partner
        CompaniesController
      PersonController
      QuoteController
```

So as you can see the CompaniesController is in the Partner folder while the other controllers are in the v1 folder.  I'm also using a RoutePrefix on my CompaniesController such as...

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/partner/companies")]
public class CompaniesController : BaseApiController{

   [Route("contact")]
   [HttpPost]
   public IHttpActionResult Contact(string id)
   {
   }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that the following url returns a 404.

```
https://localhost:44322/api/v1/partner/companies/contact/9da093ef-57a5-4da0-bd0e-5ac97cf304e2
```

But the following url works fine and calls the find method

```
https://localhost:44322/api/v1/partner/companies/contact?id=9da093ef-57a5-4da0-bd0e-5ac97cf304e2
```

I thought it might be my routeconfig file, so I added this to it but still doesn't act as expected.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Partner",
    url: "api/v1/partner/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Any idea what I need to change to get this working with the id as part of the url rather than a querystring parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into this, I solved this by changing the route attribute on the method.  So what used to look like [Route("contact")] now is [Route("contact/{id}")].